# GIS-based reporting and maintenance tool

Tags: postgis, google-maps, web-mapping, java, database

### Background

Conceptually, I am looking for a tool, or suite of software tools that can be readily integrated to help browse data using a GIS-based map (such as Google Maps). The proposed architecture resembles, but is not limited to, the following:

[image]

The technologies shown above are not fixed. For example, if OpenGEO can eliminate many of the components while adding others that are not listed (such as authentication and authorization), that would be most helpful.

Essentially, the architecture boils down to:

```
Map -> Filter sites -> Select sites -> CRUD
```

And:

```
Map -> Filter sites -> Select sites -> Summary Reports
```

The following sections describes these two problems in more detail, using a hypothetical (broad-brushstroke) example.

### Problem - CRUD

In the first screen, the user is prompted to filter by some arbitrary criteria (team names, regions, skills, equipment, and more) and select some sites:

[image]

The sites that match the filtered options are shown on the map and the user is then presented with a number of options that can be used to edit data:

[image]

If the user chooses Personnel, the system provides a CRUD screen:

[image]

The CRUD screens can be fairly complex, having simple code tables to drive them, such as:

[image]

### Problem - Report

The second part of the problem is very similar to the first, but instead of visiting CRUD screens, the user can choose to generate reports:

[image]

Note that the user has already selected the sites for reporting. If the user selects the equipment option, a report is generated with summary data:

[image]

### Question

What off-the-shelf software tool(s) can provide most (if not all) of these features?

Note: The interaction need not be exactly as shown, but the main use cases must be possible.

#### Use Case 1 - Populate Database

1. Define regions on a map.
2. Put sites [building locations] on a map.
3. Insert data (for each site).

#### Use Case 2 - Selection

1. System shows a map.
2. User filters by region and other criteria.
3. User selects sites.
4. System provides options (maintenance or reports).

#### Use Case 3 - Maintenance

1. User selects maintenance.
2. System presents complex CRUD.
3. User can add, edit, or delete data.

#### Use Case 4 - Reports

1. User selects report.
2. User selects type of report to generate.
3. System generates summary report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching GeoSpatialCMS, i had given [Cartaro](http://cartaro.org/) -
Geospatial CMS for webmapping gisCMS application [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/24080/3071). You can look information about cms there.

an alternativly [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/) has lots of feature for controlling application, maintance,users, privelges and all CRUD operation. i have been using geodjango for all operation. and it has lots of Spatial lookup for getting information too.

> GeoDjango is an add-on for Django that turns it into a world-class
>   geographic  Web framework. GeoDjango strives to make it as simple as
>   possible to create  geographic Web applications, like location-based
>   services. Some features include:
>
> Django model fields for OGC geometries. Extensions to Django’s ORM for
>   the querying and manipulation of spatial data. Loosely-coupled,
>   high-level Python interfaces for GIS geometry operations and data
>   formats. Editing of geometry fields inside the admin.

with geodjango you can do everything that you give above. and important think is that it comes with admin tools too. Beside this you can add Python and Django ready-to-use library with it...

i hope it helps you...